# setOnItemClickListener on ListView how to show database values

Tags: android, database, listview

I have a ListView with Contact info(name, phone number) so i want when i click in the contact name i want to show its name and phone number in a dialog box (which a have a code for it already) which is:

```
      public void ShowMessage(String titulo,String msg){
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);        
        dialogo.setMessage(msg);        
        dialogo.setTitle(titulo);       
        dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);       
        dialogo.show();
    }
```

Then i have seen about the `setOnItemClickListener` but when i try to put this up in my .java file it doens't even suggest the code, does anyone know why or how to do it?

EDIT:

```
        //LISTVIEW database CONTATO
    ListView user = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvShowContatos);
    //String = simple value ||| String[] = multiple values/columns
    String[] campos = new String[] {"nome", "telefone"};

     list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor c = db.query( "contatos", campos, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String lista = "";
    if(c.getCount() > 0) {
        while(true) {
           list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nome")).toString());
            if(!c.moveToNext()) break;
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    user.setAdapter(adapter);
```

that is the code of my listview/adapter

OBS: better if you can explain (no tuts link (better if possible))

Comment: We need a little more information... What type of adapter are you using and where does it get the `titulo` and `msg` from?

Comment: check edit, and Titulo is the title so: `ShowMessage("title/titulo here","message/msg here");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I see that you are processing a Cursor yourself and using an ArrayAdapter, understand that a SimpleCursorAdapter does this for you. See my note below.)

Anyway, change your Cursor into a class variable and try adding this in `onCreate()`:

```
user.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        c.moveToPosition(position);
        String nome = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nome"));
        String telefone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("telefone"));
        showMessage(nome, telefone);
    }
});
```

You aren't specific on how the title and message correlate to the contact's name, so I made that part up.

---

A class variable is simply a variable defined in a place that makes it visible to the entire class. For example this turns `c` into a class variable so you can use it in `onItemClick()`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    Cursor c;

    public void onCreate(...) {
        ...
        c = db.query( "contatos", campos, null, null, null, null, "nome");
        ...
    }
}
```

---

Understand that you can simplify how you read your contacts:

```
list = new ArrayList<String>();
Cursor c = db.query("contatos", campos, null, null, null, null, "nome");
int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex("nome");
while(c.moveToNext()) {
    list.add(c.getString(nameIndex));
}
```

I made a couple changes:

- You only need to fetch the index of the `"nome"` column once, it won't change unless you change the Cursor.
- `moveToFirst()` returns `true` if there is data to read and `false` if not.

This is faster to write and faster to run than your existing method.

---

A SimpleCursorAdapter is the standard adapter to bind data from your Cursor to a ListView. This will give you the same results as your original method, but with much less code.
How to use a SimpleCursorAdapter:

```
Cursor c = db.query("contatos", campos, null, null, null, null, "nome");
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c, 
        new String[] {"nome"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
user.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: i put it in the onCreate but it gives errors (the "user" variable, the onItemClickListener and on the getText)

Comment: `user` is your ListView. You need to set the OnClickListener after your code that looks like `user = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);`

Comment: ok, i havent used all the code but i have used the one to put in the onCreate and now the only thing that is showing error is the getText (it says to change to; getContext,getRight ...) what now? and the values is not showing in the app ( i compiled and no data is shown)

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer to: `((TextView) view).getText().toString()`.

Comment: yep, its right :D thanks ok, so now i also want to it to show the phone number aswell, how? and then after delete the contact(know how?)

Comment: Do you want to display the telephone number in the ListView and the Dialog? Or just the Dialog?

Comment: Ok, you will need to use a class variable. Do you know what that is or should I explain it too?

Comment: well i know what is a class but by a class variable would it be the name and phone number values in the class and then in the ShowMessage you would pull the class, right? i guess haha

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16846/discussion-between-sam-and-alexandre-f)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the adapter used in your ListView has a custom type (I'll call it ContactInfo), the following should work.

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // Get String provided to this particular row
        ContactInfo info = getListView().getAdapter().getItem(position);

        // Construct title, message etc from information within info
        showMessage("Contact Info", info);
    }
});
```